# Micronaut validation in controller request is not validating

Tags: validation, micronaut

I'm struggling with @Valid annotation which is not working. Here is the code:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>tenant</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>17</jdk.version>
    <release.version>17</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>4.2.3</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.aot.enabled>false</micronaut.aot.enabled>
    <micronaut.aot.packageName>com.example.aot.generated</micronaut.aot.packageName>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    <micronaut.test.resources.enabled>true</micronaut.test.resources.enabled>
    <exec.mainClass>com.example.Application</exec.mainClass>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.flyway</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-flyway</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-serde-jackson</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <version>3.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.openapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-openapi-annotations</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.testresources</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-resources-client</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <configFile>aot-${packaging}.properties</configFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.self="override">
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.openapi</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-openapi</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.openapi.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-spring-annotation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.spring.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.example</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=tenant-t2</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

**This is the model**

```java
@Data
@Introspected
@Serdeable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TenantCreateDTO {
    @Valid
    private TenantCreateItem item;

    @Data
    @Introspected
    @Serdeable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class TenantCreateItem {
        @NotNull(message = "Tenant name is required")
        @Size(min = 1, message = "Tenant name must not be empty")
        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String tenantName;

        @NotNull(message = "Tenant type is required")
        @Size(min = 1, message = "Tenant type must not be empty")
        @JsonProperty("type")
        private String tenantType;
    }
}
```

**This is the controller**

```java
import com.mcleod.model.dto.request.TenantCreateDTO;
import com.mcleod.model.dto.response.ApiResponse;
import com.mcleod.service.TenantService;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;

import javax.validation.*;

@Controller("/tenants")
public class TenantController {
    private final TenantService tenantService;

    public TenantController(TenantService tenantService) {
        this.tenantService = tenantService;
    }

    @Post
    @Operation(summary = "Create a new tenant", description = "Creates a new tenant")
    public HttpResponse<ApiResponse> create(@Body @Valid TenantCreateDTO tenantDTO) {
        return HttpResponse.ok().body(tenantService.create(tenantDTO));
    }
}
```

**This is the JSON request from POSTMAN**

```json
{
  "item": {
    "type": "Type 4",
    "name": null,
    "displayName": "Display 4",
    "managingTenantId": 1,
    "companyId": "Company 4",
    "groundControlUrl": "Ground 4",
    "baseApiUrl": "Base 4"
  }
}
```

Since "name" is null, Micronaut should throw a bad request exception but it is creating db record with name null.

What am I missing?

Comment: First thing I see but wont fix the issue probably. On your model the `@Introspected` is not needed since you're using `@Serdeable`. This implies Introspected. As a next thing: Have you tried w/o Lombok? Lombok messes with the byte code and can cause side effects. Try to use either Java records or plain POJOs.
Last but no least. If name should not be null in your DB, make sure that db field is declared `NOT NULL`